# Agrupar por fechas en un arrray resultados que se repiten

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Tengo 2 consultas mysql (mariadb). La primera es para traer todos los Nros, sorteos y fecha en que se realizaron y a su vez extraer los números que se repiten. En la 2da consulta hago un select para que me traiga Solo los Números Repetidos. Mi problama es que cuando imprimo todo, no lo hace agrupado (no se como hacerlo) por fecha y Nro de Sorteo

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM sorteos ORDER BY  NroSorteo desc LIMIT $limite";
$resultadoSQL1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL1);
$datos = array();
if (!empty($resultadoSQL1) AND mysqli_num_rows($resultadoSQL1)>0){

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoSQL1)){

 $datos[] = array("Numero1" => $row['Nro1'], "Numero2" => $row['Nro2'], "Numero3" => $row['Nro3'], 
 "Numero4" => $row['Nro4'], "Numero5" => $row['Nro5']);

  }


   $vector = [];
   $vector[] = $datos;
$b = [];
array_walk_recursive($vector, function($vector) use (&$b) {
 $b[] = $vector;
 });

$repetidos = array_count_values($b); 
ksort($repetidos);
 $valoresmayoresqueuno = array_filter( $repetidos, function( $valor ) {
  return  $valor > 1;
  } );

  $soloLasClaves = array_keys($valoresmayoresqueuno);
  $claves2Lista = implode(",",$soloLasClaves);
```

Y la Segunda Consulta:

```
$SQL2 = "SELECT * FROM sorteos WHERE Nro1 and Nro2 and Nro3 and Nro4 and Nro5 IN (".$claves2Lista.") ORDER BY NroSorteo desc LIMIT $limite";    

$miarray = array();
 $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL2); // ejecutamos la consulta

   if(!empty($result) AND mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

     while ($columnas = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "ID: ".$columnas['id']." Nro Sorteo : ".$columnas['NroSorteo']." Fecha Sorteo : ".$columnas['FechaSorteo']." Nro 1: ".$columnas['Nro1']. " Nro 2 : ".$columnas['Nro2']." Número 3: ".$columnas['Nro3']." Número 4: ".$columnas['Nro4']."  Número 5: ".$columnas['Nro5']." <br/>";
     }

     }       
  }
```

El echo me muestra los sorteos donde estan los numeros repetidos(y tambien los que no se repiten algo que no deseo):

```
ID: 5 Nro Sorteo:1305 Fecha Sorteo:2010-03-06 Nro1:3 Nro2: 7 Número 3: 2 Número 4: 22 Número 5: 50
   ID: 3 Nro Sorteo:1303 Fecha Sorteo:2010-03-04 Nro1:5 Nro2: 22 Número 3: 12 Número 4: 34 Número 5: 50
    ID: 2 Nro Sorteo:1302 Fecha Sorteo:2010-03-03 Nro1:4 Nro 2 : 5 Número 3: 6 Número 4: 34 Número 5: 11
   ID: 1 Nro Sorteo:1301 Fecha Sorteo:2010-03-02 Nro1:22 Nro 2 : 11 Número 3: 4 Número 4: 6 Número 5: 12
```

Pero me gustaria por ejemplo que salga:

```
Nro: 50. Aparece en el Sorteo Nro 1303 y 1305 
Nro: 22. Aparece en el Sorteo Nro 1301, 1303 y 1305
```

ó

```
Nro: 50. Aparece  el 2010-03-06 y el 2010-03-04
   Nro: 22. Aparece  el 2010-03-02, 2010-03-04 y el 2010-03-06
```

He probado con foreach y puedo llamar al numero repetido pero cuando intento ponerle la fecha o el Nro de Sorteo no lo hace. Desde ya Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es el rango de valores para cada número? El máximo que veo es 50.

Comment: @Sal asi es de1 a 50

Answer (score 0):

Si agregas una tabla con los números, sólo para pivotear:

```
CREATE TABLE numeros(
   Nro int
);
INSERT INTO numeros VALUES
  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
, (11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20) 
, (21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30)
, (31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(40)
, (41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50)
;
```

Lo que necesitas sale de una consulta usando *Conjuntos* de MySQL:

```
SELECT n.Nro
     , count(s.id) Aparece
     , group_concat(s.NroSorteo order by s.id) Sorteos
     , group_concat(s.FechaSorteo order by s.id) Fechas
  FROM numeros n
    INNER JOIN sorteos s
      ON find_in_set(n.Nro,make_set(31,Nro1,Nro2,Nro3,Nro4,Nro5))
  GROUP BY n.Nro
  ORDER BY Aparece DESC
```